# What happened to the TabWidget tutorial?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-tabs

The [TabWidget tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20100120081203/http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) was apparently removed from the Android developer website.  Why was this removed?  Is there an updated tutorial available?

Comment: Probably because it used a `TabActivity` which is deprecated and should be avoided in favor of `Fragments`.

Comment: I think its because they don't recommend using it and/or because they have put the code in samples. Noticed the same thing when searching for sample sync adapter tutorial. by the way, interesting site, wayback machine. thanks :-)

Comment: @Luksprog change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using Navigation Tabs in the Action Bar. If your build target is Pre-Honeycomb you can incorporate navigation tabs into ActionBarSherlock very nicely.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 2):

The `TabWidget` tutorial was removed because it used a `TabActivity`, a class which is deprecated and *should be avoided* in favor of [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)(available on older versions of android through the compatibility package).